# Failover in postgresql9.0

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I have setup Streaming replication. WAL receiver and sender process are running.
I have made the entry for trigger_file in recovery.conf file.
When I trigger failover, Its creating trigger file but failover didnt happen and standby database still is in recovery mode. it doesnt change to production.

Please help me how to trigger failover successfully.

Comment: How did you do to trigger the standby?

Comment: Better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you please provide your recovery.conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup Streaming replication successfully, then you can do the failover. If you want to activate the standby node, just create the trigger file which is configured in the file "$PGDATA/recovery.conf".

If you can not active the standby node, paste the information about the log.